# Insert a value as a reference type to Firestore (Retool)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, retool

On **Retool**, I'm trying to insert the value **"coll_2/doc_1"** as a **reference type** to **Firestore** but the type of inserted value in **Firestore** is **"string"**:

[image]

This is the **query settings**:

[image]

**Collection**:

[image]

**Value**:

[image]

```js
{ 
  myRef: "coll_2/doc_1",
}
```

Are there any ways to insert the value as a **reference type**?

Comment: I'm not familiar with RETOOL. Can you show the **ADVANCE** panel if there is a choice in advance to insert a value as a reference type?

Answer (score 1):

The value of **"myRef"** must be the **object** which has **"$ref"** as a **key**:

[image]

```js
{ 
  myRef: {"$ref": "coll_2/doc_1"},
}
```

Finally, you can insert the value as a **reference type** to **Firestore**:

[image]