# Insert a value as a reference type to Firestore using the REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

When trying to create or update a document which contains a reference type field, the value sent over the document API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.databases.documents) is stored as string, rather than a document reference.

The most similar question I've found is this [Insert a value as a reference type to Firestore (Retool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073907/insert-a-value-as-a-reference-type-to-firestore-retool), but this is only useful for retool.

This is an example of the object for the "fields" key in the body of the request

```
 {
    "datetime_visit":1649431229,
    "visited_partner":"partners/randomID",
    "ticket_amount":null
    "estatus":"Por asignar"
}
```

I´m expecting that "visited_partner" field is inserted as a document reference. [Here an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSdBo.png). Instead, it is [inserted as a string.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq5rl.png)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - it's hard to help without sample code.

Comment: What is the code that you're using?

Comment: Maybe you could manually add a reference value in the console, read it out through the rest API, and see what it looks like?  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ArrayValue#value) suggests that it's a string value with a specific sort of formatting.