# Firebase reference typedata goes wrong to be array (Retool)

Tags: retool

When I tried to add a Reference datatype to my Firebase db in Retool on raw mode,
the trouble is coming out that.
[the reference datatype is stored as a array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ok2u.png)
Here is my code

```
const data = {
   User: { $ref:"User/LjHVAMlm0yY3o5tktIkZ00aN0oC2" },
   }

db.firestore().collection('Ticket').doc().set(data);
```

Is it any solution? Thanks!

I have tried the solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073907/insert-a-value-as-a-reference-type-to-firestore-retool)

```
{ 
const data = {
   myRef: {"$ref": "coll_2/doc_1"},
   }

db.firestore().collection('Ticket').doc().set(data);
}
```

The wrong array datatype is also coming out too.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kboU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTpAt.png)